# Update field if other field has duplicate in same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table called colors.  In this table are two fields: color, and is_duplicate. I want to place a 1 in the is_duplicate field if there are more than one of the same values found in the color column.

This is what I have tried so far, but it comes back with errors as I am new to the mysql syntax.

```
update colors
set is_duplicate = 1
where color 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I am doing this so I can then drop all of the copies of the duplicates and at a later time go back and see which records had duplicates at one time.

Any suggestions?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
update colors tab1 join (select color, count(*) as num_color
         from colors group by color 
         having count(*) > 1
        ) tab2 on tab1.color = tab2.color       
set is_duplicate = 1
```

Comment: In your example, are tab1 and tab2 referring to two different tables? I am not sure I follow.  I am trying to do this where both columns are in the same table.  Will this still work?

Comment: Sorry, tab1 is colors and tab2 is only alias for query result

Comment: When I try to run that, phpmyadmin throws this error: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'colors' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Thank you.  That worked!  Not sure I quite understand the syntax.  Guess I will need to read up on joins.